# Android WebView Word Wrapping Pinch Zoom For Text Content

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm devoloping ebook reader android projecd using WebView tool. I am zooming screen like pinch, in screen text size is growing but the texts is overflowing of screen, no wrap. How to text wrapping pinch zoom screen, are there any overload method to solve the problem? Screen has only text content. For example:

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public void increaseFont(Webview webview) {
    int font = wv.getSettings().getTextZoom();
    int newFont = font + 15;
    wwbview.getSettings().setTextZoom(newFont);
}
```

Comment: Please provide some context.